# Bowling: What is the difference between a 'ringing 10' and a 'solid 10'?

Tags: terminology, bowling

While I was watching bowling, after the first throw, only the 10 pin remained.
The ESPN commentators sometimes called it a 'ringing' 10 pin and at times a 'solid' 10 pin.

What is the difference between these 2 terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ringing 10 pin takes place when the 6 pin wraps/flies around the 10 pin, the 10 pin is struck, but the 10 pin is left standing<sub>([1](http://bowling.about.com/od/bowlingglossary/g/g_ringingten.htm))</sub>. A solid 10 pin takes place when the 6 pin wraps/flies around the 10 pin, the 10 pin remains untouched and is left standing. This is more common for right-handed bowlers.

Comment: Well, technically, A ringing 10 pin is not necessarily solid and a solid 10 pin is not necessarily ringing.  A solid 10 pin is one that is completely untouched by any other pin.  A ringing 10 pin could be wiggling, thereby not being solid.